# Angular2 self.parentView.context is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, public-method

I've got a `button` element in my `*ngFor` list item:

```
<li class="cart__item" *ngFor="let item of cartService.cart$ | async">
  <button class="button button--decr" (click)="decrItem()">-</button>
     <form action="#">
        <input type="text" id="qnt" maxlength="3" readonly="readonly" value="{item.qnt || 0}}">
     </form>
  <button class="button button--incr" (click)="incrItem()">+</button>                
</li>
```

In my service I created a `public` method (just for testing purpose)

```
incrItem() {
    alert("Test!")
}
```

Clicking on my `button` and calling `incrItem()` function causes the error:

```
Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:63:13 caused by: self.parentView.context.incrItem is not a function
```

I can't understand the cause since I imported my CartService (where I created the public method) component into AppComponent (where is my `button` rendered).

And my method is public, so I can use it in the entire app.
Didn't find working solution to me in similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move `incrItem` method from service to your component class.

You have to use component properties and methods as context for your template